# Error when initiating an array using another array in PHP class

Tags: php, arrays, class

I try to initialize an array using another array in php class. Here is the code:

```
 <?php class test
{
    var $nodeDomain = array
        ("gd88" =>"10.10.104.88", "gd02" =>"10.10.104.2");
    var $node = array
        ("x86-mysql" =>$nodeDomain['gd88'],
         "x86-hbase" =>$nodeDomain['gd02']);

    function show ()
    {
        print_r($node);
    }
}
?>
```

I got this error: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /root/workspace/php/array.php on line 6

But when I run the code without using class it works fine. I mean I run the following code:

```
var $nodeDomain = array
    ("gd88" =>"10.10.104.88", "gd02" =>"10.10.104.2");
var $node = array
    ("x86-mysql" =>$nodeDomain['gd88'],
     "x86-hbase" =>$nodeDomain['gd02']);
```

I am not quite clear about the difference of php class and php script. Can anyone explain this?

Thanks.

Comment: While you're at it: var $foo is deprecated, you must use (private|protected|public) since php 5. Also, print_r($node) won't work because it's in the objects' scope, not in the method scope. Use print_r($this->node) instead.

Comment: For further reading, have a look at [Properties](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.properties.php) `... This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.`

Comment: Thanks Berry for the kind help

Answer (score 2):

You can not use another variables when declaring class members. Try to initialize them in constructor.

```
<?php class test
{
    var $nodeDomain;
    var $node;

    public function __construct() {
       $this->nodeDomain = array("gd88" =>"10.10.104.88", "gd02" =>"10.10.104.2"); 
       $this->node = array("x86-mysql" =>$this->nodeDomain['gd88'],
         "x86-hbase" =>$this->nodeDomain['gd02']);
    }
    function show ()
    {
        print_r($node);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe change `$nodeDomain` to `$this->nodeDomain`. As `$nodeDomain` is non-existent in the scope of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try put those array-initialazing to the [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) of the test class

Answer (score 0):

You just can't reference variables in the field declarations. Where should this variable come from anyway? There are no local variables and no way to position a global statement. (Of course superglobals could work but that's obviously not implemented ;-)) Instead you can do something like this:

```
<?php class test
{
    var $nodeDomain = array
        ("gd88" =>"10.10.104.88", "gd02" =>"10.10.104.2");
    var $node;

    function __construct()
    {
      $this->node = array
        ("x86-mysql" =>$nodeDomain['gd88'],
         "x86-hbase" =>$nodeDomain['gd02']);
    }
    function show ()
    {
        print_r($node);
    }
}
?>
```

Beware that $nodeDomain must be in the scope of the constructor somehow. Either it is a global variable, so you need a `global $nodeDomain` statement before the assignment or you can pass $nodeDomain as constructor argument.

Comment: Thanks. I realize why I could not do that. Great help!